# Can withStyles be used on the result of a function?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm currently trying to apply additional styling to the result of a function that returns one of two components depending on the presence of a specific set of props, as such:

```
import React from 'react'
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar'
import AccountCircle from '@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle'

const DefaultImage = withStyles({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)',
    width: '40px',
    height: '40px',
    borderRadius: '50%'
  }
})(AccountCircle)

export default function UserAvatar(props) {
  return props.userImage ? <Avatar src={props.userImage} /> : <DefaultImage />
}
```

However, when I apply withStyles to the result, none of the additional styling appears.  Am I approaching this the right way?

```
import React from 'react'
import UserAvatar from './avatar.js'
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const UserAvatarHeader = withStyles({
  root: {
    margin: '2vh',
    float: 'right'
  }
})(UserAvatar)

export default function PageHeader(props) {
  return (
...
      <UserAvatarHeader userImage={props.userImage} />
...
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
import React from 'react'
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar'
import AccountCircle from '@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle'

const styles = {
  default: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)',
    width: '40px',
    height: '40px',
    borderRadius: '50%'
  }
}

function UserAvatar(props) {
  const { classes, userImage } = props;
  return userImage ? <Avatar src={userImage} /> : <AccountCircle className={classes.default} />
}

export default withStyles(styles)(UserAvatar)
```

I found this from the documentation: https://material-ui.com/style/icons/

please let me know if you have any further questions

Comment: Thanks for responding.  However, I'm trying to use the result of UserAvatar without additional margin styling in some situations, and only apply the addtl. margin styling in others (UserAvatarHeader).  It appears your solution would apply the styling every time UserAvatar is rendered.